# How to show div when page loads depending on a href?

Tags: jquery

I want to show the  when the page load and the url
is either test.cfm?csedept_id=17,18

Right now it is loading correctly and highlings the 'li' it belongs but 
it does not show the 'ul' when loading with the new url.

http://jsfiddle.net/zund0ycj/2/

```
<div id="nav_main">
<ul id="accordion" class="collapsible ">
<li class="emptyChild"> <a id="all" href="phonelistsearch_test.cfm?all"  onclick="changeClass('all')"  >All</a></li>
<li class="fullChild"><a  id="corporate" href="phonelistsearch_test.cfm?corporate"  onclick="changeClass('corporate')" >Corporate</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<a class="opener"></a>

  <ul>
        <cfloop query="GetDeptNum_corporate">
        <cfoutput>
        <div class="content">
        <li> <a   href="test.cfm?csedept_id=17">#csedept_name#</a> </li>
        <li> <a   href="test.cfm?csedept_id=18">#csedept_name#</a> </li>
        </div>
        </cfoutput>
        </cfloop>

   </ul>
</li>
</div>
var url = "test.cfm?csedept_id=17,18";
$(function(){
console.log(url);
  if (location.href==url){
    $('.content').show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find a match on *li*, you can simply navigate back to the root *li*, and click its opener

```
  $(this).closest("ul").parent().find("a.opener").click();
```

A working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zund0ycj/6/

Note that I've changed the *href* on the *li* so that it opens when starting the fiddle. Also, you're missing one closing *ul* just before the end of a *div*

EDIT with respect to the comment

Ok, edited to cover that case as well, when you first load the fiddle only the inner item will be highlihted. The click 'Run' on the fiddle an it will match the url wit the Corporate href

http://jsfiddle.net/zund0ycj/7/

Comment: this doesnt seem to work if href="phonelistsearch_test.cfm?corporate"